# Does C# have any kind of delegate-esque feature I can use for a type instead of a method?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I'm writing a permissions service for my app, and part of this service's responsibility is to check that a user has permission to access the particular object they are trying to change. There are around 6 six different objects that can be mutated, and they all possess a particular property called `tenant`. This tenant prop is what I need to check.

The issue is that I want to keep my code as DRY as possible, but I can't see anyway of not repeating myself in this particular situation. I have six different objects which I need to check, therefore I have six different IDs and six different calls to the database to retrieve the information I need.

I'm reluctant to write six different methods each supporting the different objects I need to check, but since the code is going to look something like the below (vastly simplified) I'm not sure if there's anything I can do differently.

```
public bool CheckUserHasPermissionForObject(string id)
        {

            var obj = _dataRepository.GetObjById(id);
            var userHasPermission = UserHasPermission(obj);
            return userHasPermission;
        }
```

I was hoping delegate types would lend a hand here but I don't think they'll help either.

Comment: Why would you write 6 different methods? You've already written it, now you just need to call it with 6 different arguments

Comment: Can you post code for 2 different objects to show the parts that are repeated?

Comment: What type of app is it? Web api?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen The issue is that I need to use EF to extract six different types of object from the database. Is the different in types which is the issue. Even if I were to use `Object` I would still need six different EF calls to get the data in the first place.

Comment: @BernardVanderBeken For simplicity sake lets say there's two fields that are repeated, `id` and `tenant`.

Comment: @jbooker ASP.NET Core API

Comment: Check this out https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased

Comment: Is the shared code _exactly_ the same or just similar?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Simplified massively for brevity sake

Comment: No, I mean is the code shared across the 6 different object types exactly the same or just similar to each other?

Comment: regarding _I have six different objects which I need to check, therefore I have six different IDs and six different calls to the database to retrieve the information I need._ Does that mean that checking the id hits 6 different tables? Or is that logic identical among all of your 6 types?

Comment: @ryanyuyu Six different tables as well, there's nothing identical about these objects aside from the two properties I've already mentioned

Answer (score 0):

There are few options there.

**Option 1: Using interfaces**

You can create an interface class that has the property `tenant`:

```
    // TODO: Rename this class
    public interface IParentClass
    {
        string Tenant { get; set; }
    }
```

Then derive all your six objects from that:

```
    // TODO: Rename this class
    public class ChildClass1 : IParentClass
    {
        public string Tenant { get; set; }
    }

    // TODO: Rename this class
    public class ChildClass2 : IParentClass
    {
        public string Tenant { get; set; }
    }
    //... TODO: Derive the others as well
```

And then modify your method to check that property like this:

```
    public bool CheckUserHasPermissionForObject(string id)
    {

        var obj = _dataRepository.GetObjById(id) as IParentClass;
        var userHasPermission = UserHasPermission(obj);
        return userHasPermission;
    }

    private bool UserHasPermission(IParentClass obj)
    {
        // TODO: Implement your check here
        if (obj.Tenant == "Whatever")
        {
            // TODO: Implement your logic here
        }
        return false;
    }
```

**Option 2: Using reflections**
You can get the value of the property called "tenant" of different objects with reflections like this:

```
var tenantValue = obj.GetType().GetProperty("tenant").GetValue(obj, null);
```

This will try to find a property called "tenant" in any object, and return the value.

---

P.S. Option 3 might be using some generics, but not sure, as the question is not that clear at this moment.

Answer (score 0):

> The issue is that I want to keep my code as DRY as possible, but I can't see anyway of not repeating myself in this particular situation. I have six different objects which I need to check, therefore I have six different IDs and six different calls to the database to retrieve the information I need.

If the logic for checking permissions is not the same, then by definition you aren't repeating yourself. Don't make your code arcane or unreadable all in the name of DRY. 
 Because you're making 6 distinct calls to the database, your options for reusing code are limited.

> I'm reluctant to write six different methods each supporting the different objects I need to check.

If the objects have different ways to verify the permissions, there is no way around this. Either the objects are all the same (and can inherit some sort of shared logic), or they aren't. Objects that look similar but aren't actually the same should be kept separate.

### My recommendation

In order to communicate similar functionality (but different implementation), I'd use an interface. Maybe something like

```cs
public interface IUserPermission
{
    string Tenant { get; set; }

    bool CheckUserHasPermissions(string id);
}
```

This interface makes the calling code more consistent and better communicates how the objects are meant to interact. Notably, this does not reduce the amount of code written. It just documents/explains the intention of the code.

### Alternative solution

Ultimately, the code will need to be able to distinguish your different types of objects. But technically you could write one giant function that switches based on object type instead of splitting the logic across the six different objects. I personally find this organization hard to read and debug, but you could technically write some sort of utility (extension) method like this:

```cs
public static bool CheckUserHasPermissions(this object obj, string id)
{
    if (obj is Type1)
        return CallDatabase1(id);

    if (obj is Type2)
        return CallDatabase2(id);

    throw new ArgumentException("Unsupported object type.", nameof(obj));
}
```